# Translating a 3D point

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, geometry

I have a line in 3d space say A(x1, y1, z1) and B(x2, y2, z2). I want to find a new point between line AB starting from A @ distance 5. How can I do that.

About my task, I have a line rendered in browser using threejs and I have to calculate points between a line at some intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract start vector from the end vector, set the length of the result vector, add start vector.

```
var A = new THREE.Vector3( your_coord_values ); // start
var B = new THREE.Vector3( your_coord_values ); // end

var C = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(B, A).setLength(5).add(A);
```

Comment: heh you beat me by 22 sec :) .... but your provided also code so this should be accepted answer +1 ...

Comment: @Spektre Don't think that I'll leave you without upvote! :D

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849. It worked for me. How to know more about these method in depth. Was not able to get good understanding on their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

simply add 5 times unit direction vector of the line to the start point:

```
C =  A + 5*(B-A)/|B-A|
```